# How to replace one blockquote tag with span tag php

Tags: php

I have   tag in my content. I need to replace all those tags by span tags: for eg:
 my contenti is wrapped like :

`<blockquote><p>my content</p></blockquote>` .

I need to replace this with :

```
<span class="highlight">content</span>
```

How can i achieve this in PHP. I tried some preg_replace but nothing worked. Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

`preg_replace('/<blockqoute>.*?<p>(.*?)<\/p>.*?<\/blockqoute>/i', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $string);`

Comment: It does not work :( .. Actually i need to remove the <p> tags inside the <blockquote> as well... only the contents should come inside span

Comment: I just edited it to add the p tags and i test before and it worked, are u assigning it to a variable? like `$replace = preg_replace('/<blockqoute><p>(.*)<\/p><\/blockqoute>/i', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $subject); echo $replace;`?

Comment: One more issue i am having is that sometimes a space comes between blockquote tag and p tag like <blockquote> <p> contennt <p/>  </blockquote> . How can we replace that as well

Comment: `preg_replace('/<blockqoute>.*?<p>(.*)<\/p>.*?<\/blockqoute>/i', '<span class="highlight">$1</span>', $string);`

Comment: I updated my answer and i also forgot to include a ? inside the pattern. But that code should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly not the best solution, but should be good enough and doesn't require regex:

```
$string = str_replace('<blockquote><p>', '<span class="highlight">', $string);
$string = str_replace('</p></blockquote>', '</span>', $string);
```

Alternatively:

```
$search = array('<blockquote><p>', '</p></blockquote>');
$replace = array('<span class="highlight">', '</span>');
$string = str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```